# Tipos de produtos no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Boa tarde.

Estou desenvolvendo um `e-commerce` utilizando `wordpress` e woocommerce.
Alguns produtos oferecidos são enviados para o cliente em mais de 1 caixa. Por exemplo: Na compra de uma cama com colchão, a estrutura de madeira vai em 1 caixa e o colchão em outra. Preciso dar um jeito, de juntar as dimensões da estrutura de madeira e do colchão em apenas um produto, para ter o cálculo exato do frete.
Achei algo na internet dos tipos de produtos do `woocommerce`, onde tem um campo de "produtos agregados", porém isso não existe no meu site e não encontrei nenhum plugin para adicioná-lo (meu `woocommerce` está na versão mais recente).

Alguém sabe me ajudar? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Este artigo explica de forma simples, alguns tipos de agrupamento de produtos no Woocommerce. E, para cada tipo, ele apresenta um plugin.

[Agrupar productos en WooCommerce](https://boluda.com/tutorial/agrupar-productos-en-woocommerce/)

Este outro fala nos produtos variáveis, que é um recurso nativo do Woocommerce

[Produtos Variáveis](https://www.evonline.com.br/configurando-produto-variavel-woocommerce/)